# Besides money, what could motivate another civilization?

Tags: society, aliens, civilization

Instead of collecting money, materials, or commodities, what could motivate another civilization or push them to excel?
Knowledge?  Curiosity? Personal improvement?  Spiritual enlightenment?  Power?  Sharing equally?  Helping each other promote a healthy and functional society?
Scientific progress?  Exploration?  Stimulation?  Better living arrangements?

Comment: You're new, so you probably haven't looked too closely at how to ask a question on here. Head to the Help Center, under help at the black bar, top of your screen.Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: individually, or collectively?

Comment: Star Trek doesn't have monies.  Well, some of them don't anyway, according to Picard.  Others do yes.

Answer (score 4):

All of the things you've mentioned are potential goals that could motivate them. The one you choose should come from what the culture of the civilisation is, and in what circumstances they find themselves.

For instance, if they are facing a common enemy who is technologically superior then this might push them to pursue scientific progress. Conversely, if the culture is very traditional then scientific progress may be viewed with hostility, in which case the people's desire to defend and champion the old ways could push them to excel in different ways.

Athens and Sparta were neighbours but they excelled in different ways because they had different cultures. At the risk of massively oversimplifying, Athens traditionally valued progress (scientific, artistic, cultural) while Sparta had a more military-focused society. Their culture and values motivated them to excel in different areas.

The ancient Sumerians lived in an area with two main rivers (the Euphrates and the Tigris) which could be harnessed through irrigation to enable farming. The need to maintain the irrigation network led to centralised government, and the resulting administration led to the development of the world's first writing system. Meanwhile, Sumer had very little in the way of natural resources so they developed an extensive trade network to procure what they lacked. In this way the Sumerians were prompted to excel by the circumstances in which they found themselves.

If you ask yourself what your civilization's culture is, and what environment they find themselves in, you will be a lot closer to finding out what motivates them.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

There are examples of cultures (or at least groups of people) who are motivated by any one of the options you listed.  If we can do it, surely an alien civilization could do it.

Perhaps a question that would be closer to home is "what is it about money that motivates us?"  That sort of questions starts to dabble in philosophy, and may open up some interesting alternatives for your alien races which reflect deeply on ourselves!  There's always something quite fitting about science fiction's ability to use an alien race to cast a mirror on our own inner selves.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all animals are motivated by the need to produce viable offspring, money is just one way to do that.

Eunuchs have no ambition that could threaten their employer, and worker bees will die to defend the hive.

Answer (score 0):

When I think the world as it is today, and look for a motivational system that excludes the 'necessities of life', I think... reputation. Heh. To make this a little more general you quickly get to the principle of ***[auctoritas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auctoritas)***.

> In ancient Rome, Auctoritas referred to the general level of prestige a person had in Roman society, and, as a consequence, his clout, influence, and ability to rally support around his will.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auctoritas